# If we create an array of objects using new Array(len).fil({}); and then add a key in any of the objects, it gets reflected in all the 3 objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

If we create an array of objects using new Array(3).fill({}); and then add any key in any of the objects, it gets reflected in all the 3 objects.

I made an array of objects like:
const arr = new Array(3).fill({});

And then I tried doing arr[0][key] = "value"

This updated the key in all 3 objects in the array.

Comment: Please make your question clearer. Are you asking why ? Or what ?

Comment: Compare to: `myObj={}; arr[0]=myObj; arr[1]=myObj; arr[2]=myObj;`

Comment: To add to the other comments here: this post does not contain an actual question. Please add one, and we can answer it.

Comment: The question is why the key gets updated in all the 3 objects? If I create an array using const arr = [{}, {}, {}], and then update a key in any one of the objects, then it won't reflect in any other object.

Answer (score 4):

You put the same object at 3 different places. It's still the same.

If you want 3 different objects, you may do this for example:

```
const arr = new Array(3).fill().map(()=>({}));
```