# why is [[],[],[]] different than new Array(3).fill([])?

Tags: javascript

So my question is the same as in the title. I saw that someone initiated a similar thing here ([If we create an array of objects using new Array(len).fil({}); and then add a key in any of the objects, it gets reflected in all the 3 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396411/if-we-create-an-array-of-objects-using-new-arraylen-fil-and-then-add-a-ke)) but while everyone accused the improper method of questioning nobody gave a clear answer.

Comment: `Array(3).fill([])` creates two arrays. `[[],[],[]]` creates four arrays. The difference is pretty   clear if you do `arr[0].push( 'foo' ); console.log( arr );` after creating the array.

Comment: The answer seemed very clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If we create an array of objects using new Array(len).fil({}); and then add a key in any of the objects, it gets reflected in all the 3 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396411/if-we-create-an-array-of-objects-using-new-arraylen-fil-and-then-add-a-ke) - I realize this seems cheeky, but I really think that the answer in the question you've linked is more than sufficient...

Comment: @Paulpro I found out exactly while trying to use push.

Comment: @DanielT. `[]` creates an array and `Array(3)` also creates an array. But `fill` doesn't create any arrays, as that is not what it is for; it just fills an existing array. So in the case of `Array(3).fill([])` there are only two arrays being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array(3).fill([])` creates 3 elements *referencing* the passed object.

The answer is clear in javascript documentation:

> The fill() method fills all the elements of an array from a start
>   index to an end index with a **static value**

Comment: lol why did you get the accept?  Mine was clearly the better answer :-P

Comment: @LeroyStav Couple possibilities: 1) This one was written about 1 minute before yours.  2) The OP sounded upset in the comments under your answer. 3) OP disagrees and thinks this is the better answer (it does quote the docs)  I upvoted you to offset the pain.

Comment: MOAR KARMA! WOO!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like the only answer in the question you linked to is perfectly clear.

Array.fill "fills" the array with *static* values.  That is to say, you are *creating on single empty array* and then referencing it in all three of the locations, hence it is the *same array* in each of the outer array's indices

Comment: @DanielT. no need of screenshots https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini In that post the only answer is " Compare to: myObj={}; arr[0]=myObj; arr[1]=myObj; arr[2]=myObj;" - which idk what that means and another which explains how to solve it. Idon't see an explanation to "why"

Comment: but to make it absolutely clear:  array.fill "fills" the array with a static value.  that is to say, you have created an array with three indices, then "filled" it with a reference to a new array.  so you have what amounts to "var inner = []; var outer = [inner, inner, inner];"

Comment: @DanielT. If you want to discuss whether this is a duplicate, you should do that under the question instead of under this answer.

Comment: I'm trying to help you productively use Stack Overflow. Why are you being rude to someone who is trying to help?